# field widget with multiple input fields

Tags: 7, entities

I need to create a custom field widget that is actually a 2 input fields group. I also need to save these values (I guess this is done through `hook_field_schema()`)

The main problem is that I'm a little bit confused about how to use `hook_field_widget_info()` and `hook_field_widget_form()` and how are these connected with the `hook_field_schema()`

Any insights / links about this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as their schema and other basic definitions, fields have

- [Widgets](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_widget/7)

  > Field API widgets specify how fields are displayed in edit forms. Fields of a given field type may be edited using more than one widget. In this case, the Field UI module allows the site builder to choose which widget to use. Widget types are defined by implementing hook_field_widget_info().
- [Formatters](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_formatter/7)

  > Field API formatters specify how fields are displayed when the entity to which the field is attached is displayed. Fields of a given field type may be displayed using more than one formatter. In this case, the Field UI module allows the site builder to choose which formatter to use. Field formatters are defined by implementing hook_field_formatter_info().

Each field needs a widget and formatter to do anything useful, but they don't necessarily have to be implemented by the same module that implements the field. For example, you could piggyback off of one of the select widgets if that made sense for your field.

For full code examples, check out the [Examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples)

Comment: I had a look at the examples modules but couldn't find what I was looking for. So I had a look at the `field/text.module` in core. This made more sense. One thing is somehow unclear: in `hook_field_widget_form()` if the returned array keys are the same as the columns in `hook_field_schema()`, they will automatically be saved in those columns in the database, right?

Comment: Yep exactly right, whatever's eventually in `$form_state['values']['field_foo']['und'][0]['my_column']` (for example) will go into the `my_column` field from your schema (it'll actually be called `field_foo_my_column` in the database but as far as the API's concerned you'll always be dealing with `my_column`)